# Abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let P(x,y, z, w)= 0 be a complex surface .  How can we know that this surface is a sub-variety of an abelian variety or not?

Comment: If this is a smooth surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$, then the answer is never: by weak Lefschetz, it is simply connected, but a subvariety of
an abelian variety is not.

Comment: assume that this is a singular surface in P^3.


Comment: @Jafar: Do you have a specific surface in mind? 

Comment: If your surface contains a rational curve then the answer is again never, as abelian varieties never contain any rational curves.

Comment: A necessary condition is that the Albanese map of a smooth model of the surface be birational. 

Comment: Could this question, please, be expanded somehow, including a more concise specification of P and an explantion what 'how can we know' should mean in detail. True, one can somehow infer/guess what might be meant, but still I think this will be a much better question with a bit of effort. Finally, a more informative title seems also desirable.  

Comment: Dear Dr. Loughan , proving that there is no rational curve in surface (variety) is usually a hard problem.  Isn't it? 

Comment: @Jafar: Yes but it depends on the surface. If you have a specific surface that you are interested in, it might be possible to say something. I concur with quid that you should clarify the question. 

Comment: In case you are not aware, you can edit the question to expand it (you do not have to, and in fact should not ask a new one); while being logged in use the link just below the tag. 

Comment: As Donu noted, if the surface is smooth the answer is no.  If arbitrary singularities are allowed, any surface (including abelian ones) has a birational model of the form $P(x,y,z,w)= 0$.  